# How to upgrade Android 1.5 R3 SDK to 2.2?

Tags: android

I haven't worked on Android development for more than a year now. The latest SDK I have on my XP machine is 1.5 R3. I'd like to update to the 2.2 SDK but the android.com guide does not apply to the SDK I have installed. For example the AVD Manager from eclipse does not show specified dialog.

Any one upgraded his SDK please let me know what to do.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the ability for the Android SDK to update itself with new platform versions (the dialog you're not seeing) came out *after* the 1.5 R3 SDK.

The easiest thing to do is go to the [SDK page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and download the newest version of the SDK.  From there you'll be able to follow the guide you mentioned without problem.